# How can I change the geth version from 1.5 to 1.3.5?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

The 1.5 version of geth is not stable, how can I change it to 1.5.3?

Comment: that's depend by your OS

Answer (score 0):

Note, the latest stable version at the time of writing this is [1.4.8](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases).

You can download the official releases from [github](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases):

- geth-ARM-20160624151653-1.4.8-98be7cd.tar.bz2
- geth-Linux64-20160624182400-1.4.8-98be7cd.tar.bz2
- Geth-Win64-20160624152318-1.4.8-98be7cd.zip

If you need 32 bit builds or use any other operating system, you can download the crossbuilds from [bintray](https://bintray.com/karalabe/ethereum/geth/):

- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-linux-arm-6.tar.bz2
- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-android-21.aar.tar.bz2
- wallet-0.7.6-geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-darwin-amd64.tar.bz2
- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-darwin-10.6-386.tar.bz2
- wallet-0.7.6-geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-windows-386.zip
- wallet-0.7.6-geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-windows-amd64.zip
- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-ios-7.0-framework.tar.bz2
- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-linux-arm-7.tar.bz2
- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-windows-4.0-386.exe.zip
- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-linux-arm-5.tar.bz2
- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-linux-arm64.tar.bz2
- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-darwin-10.6-amd64.tar.bz2
- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-linux-386.tar.bz2
- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-linux-amd64.tar.bz2
- geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-windows-4.0-amd64.exe.zip
- wallet-0.7.6-geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-linux-amd64.tar.bz2
- wallet-0.7.6-geth-1.4.8-stable-98be7cd-linux-386.tar.bz2

To install the new version, all you need to do is downloading it and running it. The 1.4.8 release should be backwards compatible with the 1.5.x unstable branch.

In any case, [make backups of your keys first](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/109/87)!